# What is the issue in this Mysql query

Tags: mysql, select

I am having a mysql query problem in my project.

There are 3 tables named product, product_option, product_category

This is data for product_option:

```
mysql> select * from product_option where product_id = 2;
+-------------------+------------+
| product_option_id | product_id |
+-------------------+------------+
|                 2 |          2 |
|                 3 |          2 |
|                 4 |          2 |
+-------------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is data for product_category:

```
mysql> select * from product_category where product_id = 2;
+-------------+------------+
| category_id | product_id |
+-------------+------------+
|          15 |          2 |
|           2 |          2 |
|           4 |          2 |
+-------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want to select product with these options and category.

This is how I tried it. But its giving 9 rows. (its duplicating category_id and option_id 3 times)

```
mysql> SELECT p.product_id
    ->      , p.product_name
    ->      , p.enabled
    ->      , p.date_available
    ->      , pc.category_id
    ->      , po.product_option_id
    -> FROM  product p
    -> INNER JOIN `product_category` pc USING(product_id)
    -> LEFT JOIN `product_option` po USING(product_id)
    -> WHERE p.product_id = 2;
+------------+--------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
| product_id | product_name | enabled | date_available | category_id | product_option_id |
+------------+--------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |          15 |                 2 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |           2 |                 2 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |           4 |                 2 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |          15 |                 3 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |           2 |                 3 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |           4 |                 3 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |          15 |                 4 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |           2 |                 4 |
|          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |           4 |                 4 |
+------------+--------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I also tried it something like this:

```
SELECT p.product_id
     , p.product_name
     , p.description
     , p.meta_title
     , p.meta_description
     , p.meta_key_word
     , p.brand
     , p.quantity
     , p.price
     , p.enabled
     , p.date_available
     , pc.category_id
     , po.product_option_id
FROM  product p
INNER JOIN (
          SELECT product_id, category_id
          FROM   product_category
          GROUP  BY product_id
          ) pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT product_id, product_option_id
          FROM   product_option
          GROUP  BY product_id
          ) po ON po.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE p.product_id = 2\G
```

But neither works for me.
can anybody tell me what would be this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Your query looks correct.  You are getting a cartesian product between categories and options because that is the query you are writing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, can you tell what it is duplicating category_id and product_option_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have answered that you're getting a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of product options and product categories. That's the answer to your question "what is the issue with this query?"

You probably also want to know how to change the query so that it does *not* return a Cartesian product. I can think of two solutions:

1. Execute one query for each join, and don't try to combine them into one query. You will get two result sets, which you then must fetch in your application code and combine into whatever data structure you want to represent one "product" object.

   ```
   SELECT p.product_id
        , p.product_name
        , p.description
        , p.meta_title
        , p.meta_description
        , p.meta_key_word
        , p.brand
        , p.quantity
        , p.price
        , p.enabled
        , p.date_available
        , pc.category_id
   FROM  product p
   INNER JOIN (
             SELECT product_id, category_id
             FROM   product_category
             GROUP  BY product_id
             ) pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
   WHERE p.product_id = 2

   SELECT p.product_id
        , po.product_option_id
   FROM  product p
   LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT product_id, product_option_id
             FROM   product_option
             GROUP  BY product_id
             ) po ON po.product_id = p.product_id
   WHERE p.product_id = 2
   ```

You may think, "I have to get all the data in one query, because I'm using a programming tool or framework that requires it!" This is not a good reason. Many domain objects require multiple SQL queries to fetch all their data. If you're using a framework that doesn't support real-world applications, then you should change the framework.

2. Reduce the results from each joined table to one row, so that a Cartesian product is only multiplying 1x1 row.

   ```
   SELECT p.product_id
        , p.product_name
        , p.description
        , p.meta_title
        , p.meta_description
        , p.meta_key_word
        , p.brand
        , p.quantity
        , p.price
        , p.enabled
        , p.date_available
        , GROUP_CONCAT(pc.category_id) AS category_id_list
        , GROUP_CONCAT(po.product_option_id) AS product_option_id_list
   FROM  product p
   INNER JOIN (
             SELECT product_id, category_id
             FROM   product_category
             GROUP  BY product_id
             ) pc ON pc.product_id = p.product_id
   LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT product_id, product_option_id
             FROM   product_option
             GROUP  BY product_id
             ) po ON po.product_id = p.product_id
   WHERE p.product_id = 2
   GROUP BY p.product_id

   +------------+--------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
   | product_id | product_name | enabled | date_available | category_id | product_option_id |
   +------------+--------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
   |          2 | dsfad        |       1 | 2016-10-18     |      2,4,15 |             2,3,4 |
   +------------+--------------+---------+----------------+-------------+-------------------+
   ```

This solution returns the list of categories and product options as comma-separated strings, not as individual items, so your application code that fetches the results will have to split the string into its elements.

Answer (score 0):

*Can anybody tell me what would be this issue?*

I'm answering this question from your post. This behaviour is expected and your query is correct. You are getting a cartesian product with categories and options since you do not have a relationship between them.

So you have 1 product, 3 options and 3 categories. Your query is producing rows for each unique pair, so you get `1*3*3 = 9` rows in your output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your query has no issue. The result is correct also according to
   your query.
2. There is no duplicated row in the result. Your result
   contains 9 rows with 9 different combinations of category_id and
   product_option_id. For example, you have 3 rows with the same category_id =
   15 along with 3 different product_option_id values 2, 3, 4.

   - 15, 2
   - 15, 3
   - 15, 4